# Integration from SalesForce into a SharePoint Dashboard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-integration

Our Sales teams are tracking their sales objectives on SalesForce and they would like 2 of the reports (graphics mostly, as shown below) to be visible from their SharePoint team site. Is it possible? If so, how?

[image: Example 2][image: Example 1]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do it without 3rd party tools.

- 1st you need a connector to connect the Salesforce and SharePoint.
- Then develop a Dashboard in SharePoint on the base of data.

http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/cloud-connector/Pages/Office-365-Salesforce-Integration-Migration-Replication.aspx

http://www.slideshare.net/Netwoven/integrating-salesforce-and-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @WaqasSarwar, there is no direct way since Microsoft has not developed any direct API that plug in data from Salesforce to Sharepoint.

Just expanding on the answer, there are 3 ways you can achieve this:

- Integrating using a third party system installed adapter
- Integrating using a Microsoft Azure hosted service
- Integrating using a third party integration service.

Indepth steps for all 3 methods [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-integrate-sharepoint-salesforce-pratyush-kumar).